# why do we need to create new instence of Icollection type property

Tags: c#

I have a couple of properties in my class which are of ICollection type. When I try to add any data in those properties without creating their new instance compiler shoots me an error saying I need to create instance of them. My question is, when I create a new instance of a class, then indirectly I create a new memory for the entire class and those properties (ICollection type) are inside class, so why do I need to create new instance for those properties.

```
public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    public string AddressId { get; set; }

}

public class Contact
{
    public string ContactId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User user = new User();

        user.Contacts = new Collection<Contact>() {new Contact() {}};

        user.Addresses.Add(new Address()
        {
        });//Throws Error

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `ICollection` is an `interface` and interfaces are [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2(v=vs.110).aspx). That means by creating a variable, you did not create an instance. That only happens when you call `new`. You only created a reference to an instance.

By default, a reference is `null` which means it's not set to any particular instance. That's why when you call a method on a reference that was not set to an instance, you get a [NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with everything that nvoigt said in their answer. All reference type properties (anything other than int, DateTime, string, etc.) defaults to a `null` when they are a property on a new object.

What you'll want to do in order to get around that `NullReferenceException` is to instantiate all of those properties when you create a new object.

```
public User() {
    this.Addresses = new List<Address>();
    this.Contacts = new List<Contact>();
}
```

With that in your constructor, you'll be able to add items to those collections without having to instantiate them outside your objects.